# How to validate Angular Material Datepicker?

Tags: angular-material

I have the following code:

```
<form [formGroup]="meetingFormGroup">

                  <!-- Date Input -->
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <input
                      matInput
                      [min]="minDate"
                      [max]="maxDate"
                      [matDatepicker]="picker"
                      placeholder="Choose a date"
                      formControlName="date"
                      required
                    >
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>

                    <mat-error *ngIf="meetingFormGroup.controls['date'].hasError('required')"
                      >Please choose a date.</mat-error
                    >
                    <mat-error *ngIf="?????"
                      >Entered date is too small.</mat-error
                    >
                  </mat-form-field>
                </form>
```

Now on the [Angular Material Website](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) at the 'Date Validation' section I read the following:

Each validation property has a different error that can be checked:

```
A value that violates the min property will have a matDatepickerMin error.
A value that violates the max property will have a matDatepickerMax error.
A value that violates the matDatepickerFilter property will have a matDatepickerFilter error.
```

So my question is, how can I validate these errors in my mat-error tags. What do I need to write in the *ngIf expression field?

I am sorry for my bad English and hope you understand my problem and maybe can provide a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the Angular Material website ([here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-validation)):

> - A value that violates the min property will have a `matDatepickerMin` error.
> - A value that violates the max property will have a `matDatepickerMax` error.
> - A value that violates the matDatepickerFilter property will have a `matDatepickerFilter` error.

So, you'll use:

- For min - `meetingFormGroup.controls['date'].hasError('matDatepickerMin')`
- For max - `meetingFormGroup.controls['date'].hasError('matDatepickerMax')`
- For filter - `meetingFormGroup.controls['date'].hasError('matDatepickerFilter')`.

Answer (score 0):

Template:

```html
<mat-error *ngFor="let error of getErrorMessages(control)">{{ error }}</mat-error>
```

Using this approach you can list all Error messages in mat-error instance  and will display list of error messages.

```js
getErrorMessages(control: AbstractControl): string[] {
  const errors = {};

  if (control?.errors) {
    const controlErrors = control.errors;

    if (controlErrors?.matDatepickerMin) {
     // Any custom logic in case needs to apply
      errors['matDatepickerMin'] = 'Min Date can't be less than e.g 2024/01/01';
    }

    if (controlErrors?.matDatepickerMax) {
         // Any custom logic in case needs to apply
      errors['matDatepickerMax'] = 'Max Date can't be less than e.g 2024/12/31';
    }

    if (controlErrors?.matDatepickerFilter) {
     // Any custom logic in case needs to apply
      errors['matDatepickerFilter'] = 'Invalid date';
    }
  }

  if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  return Object.keys(errors).map(key => {
    switch (key) {
      case 'matDatepickerMin':
      case 'matDatepickerMax':
      case 'matDatepickerFilter':
        return errors[key];
      default:
        return '';
    }
  });
}
```